# fail to combine ModelBinderAttribute and FromBody for controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

Following a .Net Framework to .Net Core MVC migration,
The Combination between [Modelbinder] with a second complex type in a controller action parameter does not seem to work anymore.

E.g. of method which I try to call:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetResult([ModelBinder(typeof(ComplexDynamicModelBinder))] dynamic dynamicFormModel, [FromBody] RandomComplexType complexType) { 
// Do Something 
}
```

E.g. of call from Js:

```
const fetchHeaders = new Headers([
   ['__RequestVerificationToken', 'myveriftoken'],
   ['x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest'],
   ['Content-Type', 'application/json']
]);
fetch(urlToAction, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({
      dynamicFormModel: { someProperties: "values" },
      complexType: { someProperties: "values" }
   }),
   headers: fetchHeaders
})
.then(console.log);
```

All my different attempts always get a 415 ...

Thank you for your future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

415 is usually a data type mismatch error. Since I don't know what your model and `ComplexDynamicModelBinder` are, I didn't use `[ModelBinder]` and built a model based on your data, you can use it as a reference.

Model:

```
public class RandomComplexType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
        
}
public class ViewModel
{ 
    public RandomComplexType complexType { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const fetchHeaders = new Headers([
   ['__RequestVerificationToken', 'myveriftoken'],
   ['x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest'],
   ['Content-Type', 'application/json']
]);
fetch('/Home/GetResult', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({
        dynamicFormModel: { someProperties: "values" },
        complexType: { "Id": 1, "Name": "Name1" }  
   }),
   headers: fetchHeaders
})
.then(console.log);
```

Test Result:
[image]

You can check what the data you send looks like and whether it complies with the standard in the developer tools of the browser:
[image]

Comment: Thank for your anwser, it almost work but when I try your code, I get an exception when trying to access the "someProperties" property of the "dynamicFormModel" -> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'someProperties''

Comment: I tried a lot of things yesterday and today, it seems I misinterpreted the results of some of my tests, the example seems to work and as my mindelbinder assigns a type to the model dynamic, all is good, thanks !